# Bluetooth LE Scanner Thread

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth

I'm very new to Android development and I'm currently trying to make an app that receives messages from a blue tooth LE device. The information it sends is very important and I'm doing heavy computation each time I get a scan. My question is should I be putting this scan method on a separate thread? Also, during the beginning the app tends to scan in fast and then the scans get very slow, and I'm not sure why, thoughts?

Comment: Did you get my answer? or you need something else?

Comment: For BLE scan, hope this https://github.com/RustFisher/BluetoothScanner could help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to start the scanning from separate thread, the low energy scanners are callback based and already runs in separate threads.

Please take a look on [BluetoothLeScanner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html) and startLeScan method of Bluetooth adapter:

```
BluetoothManager bluetoothManager = (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE); 
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

bluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(yourCallback); // API 21+
bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(yourCallback); // API 18+
```

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but I didn't see any information about thread used for BLE scanning in the documentation. Like usual with Android "documentation".